# Problems setting up minted and tcolorbox to include source code and set title

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, code, compilation-error

For my PhD thesis, I am using `minted` package for source code listings. I'd like to have a custom command `\mylisting` something along the lines of

```
\mylisting[Name in title]{filename of source code}
```

or
    \mylisting{Hello world}{hello_world.java}

I tried reading the `tcolorbox` manual, and the closest I got to was the following minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most,minted]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting{\mylisting}[2][]{%
    listing engine=minted,minted language=java,minted style=colorful,
    listing file={#2},
    title=Listing (\thetcbcounter) of #2,
listing only,breakable,#1}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\mylisting[Hello world]{hello_world.java}  % problematic line!!
\mylisting{Hello world}{hello_world.java}  % problematic line!! 

\end{document}
```

But due to my lack of knowledge in TeX, this fails and produces lots of errors. I particularly found it hard to even include the source code from the `hello_world.java` file located in the same directory as the `mnwe`.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    // A 'Hello World' in Java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

What might be the problem here, and how do I solve this?

Comment: Do you want something like `\newtcbinputlisting{\mylisting}[2][]{%
    listing engine=minted,minted language=java,minted style=colorful,
    listing file={#2},
    title={#1},
listing only,breakable}`? The code in the question has two problems: (1) The optional argument is passed on as option to `\newtcbinputlisting`, so if we write `\mylisting[Hello world]{hello_world.java}` the macro tries to call a colorbox with the option `Hello World`. But an option like this does not exist. So you probably wanted `title={#1}`. ...

Comment: @moewe, Yes. I have tried that and get the error ```(Package pgfkeys)  I do not know the key '/tcb/Hello world'```

Comment: ... (2) As posted the macro tries to write the file name given in its second (mandatory) argument as title. But the file name has an underscore in it, that causes problems.

Comment: Did you really try with `\newtcbinputlisting{\mylisting}[2][]{% listing engine=minted,minted language=java,minted style=colorful, listing file={#2}, title={#1}, listing only, breakable}`?

Comment: @moewe, I am sorry. That worked! I am sorry for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with the code

1. The optional argument is simply passed on to `tcolorbox` as a general argument. It seems to be used, however, as a title argument, so `#1` should not be written bare, but as value of the `title` option.
2. `title=Listing (\thetcbcounter) of #2` actually uses the second argument (the file name) as title. The filename in your example contains an underscore `_`, and that has a special meaning.

In the comments it emerged you want

```
\newtcbinputlisting{\mylisting}[2][]{%
  listing engine=minted, minted language=java, minted style=colorful,
  listing file={#2}, listing only,
  title={#1},
  breakable}
```

upon which your MWE now gives

[image]

as desired.